# svchost.exe is eating up the memory

Tags: svchost

svchost.exe is eating up my memory and my laptop is damn slow. When I checked the services of that svchost, its giving these many services.

wudfsvc, WPDbusenum, wlansvc, uxsms, trkwks, sysmain, pcasvc, netman, cscservice, audioendpoint.

All has the same PID which is 6156. Please assist me on this.

Comment: Please specify your Windows version (I bet it's 7) and how much memory you have in total, and in that svchost.exe process.

Comment: sysmain is Superfetch, which is preloading/precaching frequently used apps in memory. You can disable it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SysInternals **Process Explorer** (free download from Microsoft's Technet site) to get a better perception of the services (with pretty names).
2. In my Windows 7, I have all those services running under the same svchost.exe, except `WPDbusenum` (Portable Device Enumerator) and `cscservice` (Offline Files).
3. Try stopping those services from `services.msc` console, and see if it helps. I would do it one by one, starting with `cscservice`. Also `Superfetch` is a candidate, it handles a lot of memory, but it shouldn't be a problem when it's running fine (in fact, it tries to help performance).
4. Once you know the culprit, try to **find out why** it's gone memory-hungry. These are very common system services, very tested, they shouldn't be causing anything wrong.